# Fetching all PHP files and store their size

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, filesystems, find

I like to monitor every php file with their size (and if a new file has been added).
On my server are more than 200 000 of em so `find` takes very long.

This is what I do:

```
ls -1 --size $(find -P . -type f -name "*.php")
```

This takes hours.

Is there anything I can do to make this monitoring faster? (Except a faster Server)
Or is there any trick that give a file list with file size or crc32 ?

In addition I do not know if this would be faster:

```
find . -P -type f -name "*.php" -exec ls -1 --size \{} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command has a `-printf` option that can be used to print the size of the file without having to exec ls

```
find . -name '*.php' -printf "%p %s\n"
```

You can use the [sha512sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha512sum) (or [md5sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum)) to take a list of files and produce hashes for them which can later be used to check their integrity

```
find . -name '*.php' | while read line; do sha512sum "$line"; done
```

If you capture the output of the command above to a file you can then use sha512sum to check their integrity

```
sha512sum -c file
```

Comment: Will it be faster with additional filter like "-type f" or -P to not follow symlinks?

Comment: @MikePretzlaw: You should be able to test this yourself using time find ...

Answer (score -2):

Use OSSEC for integrity check.

Comment: You might go into detail about how you would use OSSEC to do an integrity check.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the <only> optimal answer (If you want to solve the problem). If you'll find something better for this - don't forget to inform whole world about the new super-duper integrity check solution. OSSEC is de-facto standard.
And the chance that ossec.net will become unavailable or sold is smaller than serverfault.com will die. If you want to know how to use it - read documentation, it's easier to setup, no need to waste time for writing anything. This site is about answers, not the documentation. Do you still need to check integrity/checksum of files even if file timestamp wasn't changed?

Comment: There are a whole slew of reasons why link only answers aren't valued here.  Respect the feedback that others give you.  Read http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Link removed. :)

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that your aren't trolling.  Link to the site by all means, but why not include some context with your answer, like how to use OSSEC for integrity check.  That adds value to the link and makes for a good answer.

Comment: What is wrong with OSSEC? It doesn't work? Cannot solve your problem?

Comment: Your explanation of why ossec is the only solution would be great, if you put it in your answer! Comments are ephemeral, and some users do not even see them at all.

Comment: I understand Michael, but I do like links, and if someone doesn't, here is the answer without link. Q: How would you use it? A: Read documentation. "I don't like links". Link removed. I'm not saying this is the only or best answer. It might be. So, OSSEC isn't an answer? Honestly, it is. I cannot copy end-to-end manual to the answer. "I want to serve webpage, Is there any software that can do that?" -> "Yes, apache web server can do that, take a look at http://httpd.apache.org", "oh, You might go into detail about how you would use apache to do so, i don't like links" :)

Comment: It's not that people don't like links.  Its answers that ONLY have links - so don't do much more than Google, and if the link goes dead all the value of the answer is gone.  But you seem wilful in not understanding this, so welcome to your downvotes...